# Generating Random Values in pl/sql

Tags: random, plsql

I try to generate random value in pl/sql. But i need these values must be fix **12 character**.

For example 654696544846, 234864687644, 438792168431

Thanks.

Comment: rpad(substr(dbms_random.value, 2, 12), 12, 0)

Comment: Take a look at this [DBMS_RANDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i998095)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a strictly numeric string made of decimal characters, you can use the dbms_random.value function which, when given 2 values X and Y, returns a random number between X (included) and Y (excluded)

```
  select trunc(dbms_random.value(100000000000,1000000000000)) from dual
```

if you can accept also alphanumeric chars, you can use the dbms_random.string function:

```
  select dbms_random.string('X',12) from dual
```

the second parameter is the required string length, the first dictates the subset of characters that are allowed in the string

```
 'u', 'U' - uppercase alpha characters
 'l', 'L' - lowercase alpha characters
 'a', 'A' - mixed case alpha characters
 'x', 'X' - uppercase alpha-numeric characters
 'p', 'P' - any printable characters.
```

source: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help @Carlo

Answer (score 1):

dbms_random.value returns a value between 0 and 1 with a precision of 39 digits, which you then multiply by 1000000000000 to get 12 digit number. It has a decimal part was well which can be removed with a suitable call to `to_char` which will also format it with a constant length.

```
select to_char(dbms_random.value * 1000000000000,'fm000000000000') from dual;
```

Comment: Can you provide any explanation in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @meetar, what is confusing you about this answer?

Comment: dbms_random.value would return me a value between 0 and 1 with a precision of 39 digits, so i am multiplying it with 1000000000000 to get 12 digit number with decimal part was well. After that, i am using to_char to discard the decimal part

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged, and likely to result in deletion flags – including explanation or commentary in your answers will help people learn, and make your answers more visible on search engines! cc @JeffreyKemp

Comment: @meetar, normally yes - but in some cases (like this) it's seems so bleedingly obvious that it is probably not necessary, I think :) But just in case I've adapted trijit's comment into the answer.